# Auto scroll to next option in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, onclick

I am very new to JS. How do I add onclick event to magento Advanced options so when selected first option it should automatically scroll (jump) to next option without having to manually scroll for the next option. Here is an example: [Link to Example](http://shop.soeasyrider.com/index.php/so-easy-rider-v5-support-gps-moto-et-grands-smartphones.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged 'jQuery' in your post I'm going to assume you want to use that.

Below is the code that would work on the example you gave, but it (especially the selectors) will be different for other templates.

```
// Click event handler
$('.optionblock input').click(function(){
    // Check if there is a next option block
    var $next = $(this).parents('.optionblock').next('.optionblock');
    if($next.length) {
        // Set scroll position to the next option block
        $(window).scrollTop($next.offset().top);
    }
});
```

This is just to get the idea. I didn't consider crossbrowser support and animated scroll effects.

**Update:** here you have a working example with the animated scroll effect: http://jsfiddle.net/66AmA/

**Update 2:** For your specific HTML-structure the code would be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FFu6n/

Comment: hi, all the functions are inside `<li></li>` which does not have any class and there is no way to add one as it is autogenerated. Is there any way to make it work with `<li></li>`? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it would still be possible. But you need to provide the full HTML-structure, otherwise I cannot help you. For example, is there a class or ID on the `ul`-element in which the `li`-elements are located?

Comment: I have added the entire script at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FlourishDNA/7WpvQ/1/)

Comment: At the link you provided there is only one product option, so no scrolling will happen. But, I updated my answer with multiple options that have (about) the same HTML-structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define "onChange" event to focus next input (or use other condition than onchange):

```
document.getElementById("myForm").elements[next].focus();
```